# How to turn off laptop speakers when headphones plugged in on Debian?

Tags: laptop, speakers, headphones, debian-lenny

I'm running Debian Lenny on Toshiba P200-10C and whenever I plug in the headphones
small laptop speakers won't turn off. Kernel version is 2.6.18-5-686, alsa version is 1.0.16-2.

Speakers turn off like they should in Vista.

Answer (score 1):

*Auto-mute speakers when headphones are plugged in* - Debian User Forums:

> http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=57796